# Transactions per second

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to display particular column transactions per second count for each second.

The below query works for each minute.

```
Select DISTINCT column1 AS Event, Count( column1 ) AS count,
DateAdd(MINUTE, DateDiff(MINUTE, 0, [dateTimeColumn]), 0) as Time
From table
  Group By column1 ,DateAdd(MINUTE, DateDiff(MINUTE, 0, [dateTimeColumn]), 0)
```

Test data as below:

```
Event   Time
A        21:01:01
A        21:01:02
A        21:02:01
```

This results as

```
Event    Count  Time
A         2     21:01
A         1     21:02
```

The results should be at seconds level

```
Event    Count  Time
A         1     21:01:01
A         1     21:01:02
A         1     21:02:01
```

But I now need the transactions per second rather than minute. When I give DateDiff(Second...) it is giving error as date overflow error.

Please suggest

Comment: Use a newer date like `2000-01-01` instead of `0` to avoid numeric overflow

Comment: You refer to "dateTimeColumn", but in your test data you're only showing "time". What is the actual table structure?

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
;WITH CTE_MinTime AS (SELECT MIN(dateTimeColumn) AS min_time FROM Table)
SELECT
    T.column1 AS Event,
    COUNT(*) AS [count],
    DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, MT.min_time, T.dateTimeColumn), MT.min_time) AS [Time]
FROM
    CTE_MinTime MT
CROSS JOIN Table T
GROUP BY
    T.column1,
    DATEADD(SECOND, DATEDIFF(SECOND, MT.min_time, T.dateTimeColumn), MT.min_time)
```

The problem is that when you do the `DATEDIFF` it's counting seconds from 1900-01-01, which is too big of a number for the default datatype.